# Using "git rebase onto" to merge two feature branches?

Tags: git

I made one feature branch, from master:

```
git checkout -b branch1
+ commits to this branch
git push
```

Later someone else made a second branch on GitHub, then I fetched that branch and edited it:

```
git checkout branch2
+ commits to this branch
git push
```

I expected we would get branch2 into master, and that then I would get the latest master (with branch2) into my branch1.

But now I'm told they don't want branch2 in master by itself -- and that instead I should get branch2 into my branch1, and push branch2 as part of branch1 when branch1 is complete.

So I'm trying to get branch2 into my branch1. I try the following ...

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase --onto branch2
git log
```

... but git log shows that the rebase obtained the original version of branch2 and not the additional branch2 change that I made.

How can I get the whole of the current branch2 into my branch1?

If I use git merge instead of git rebase then it works (i.e. gets all the commits that were made in branch2 ... and adds them to the head of branch1):

```
git checkout branch1
git merge branch2
git log
```

I don't understand why git rebase didn't get all the branch2 commits, but only the first one?

Answer (score 1):

When I am rebasing one branch on another I always follow these steps:

1. git pull
2. git checkout on branch to be rebased
3. git rebase -i **origin/targetBranch**

If your local repo is updated check if branches are in the same place with origin or use prefix **origin/** in your rebase command.